# Disable minimize in fast report 6

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe, fastreport

Is it possible disable minimize in fast report 6?

For some reason in delphi fastreport is minimized automatically.

Only close and maximize button.

Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write in the `OnPreview` event handler

```
procedure TForm1.frxReport1Preview(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(frxReport1.PreviewForm) then
      frxReport1.PreviewForm.BorderIcons := [TBorderIcon.biSystemMenu, TBorderIcon.biMaximize]
end;
```

And as you can see the minimize button is disabled[image]

Note that the `PreviewForm` will be created only when you show the report, so the `OnPreview` event handler is the right place to write your code.